# Creating buffers to closest distances with two categories in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, buffer, polygon-creation, knn

I would like to develop an expression that does the following nearest-neighbour analysis:

From a layer of points 'point_layer', I would like to calculate for each point the distance to the nearest point.

Once this distance value is calculated, the goal is to draw the buffer with the distance as a radius value and then symbolize the buffers with two categories:

- Red green: points (buffers) located within 70 centimetres
- Red red: points (buffers) located outside of 70 centimetres

Below I show a manual result recreation that should be obtained:

[image]

For my part, to try to obtain the expected result, I am working on this idea:

1. To obtain the closest distances to each point I use the following function:

   ```
   array_sum (array_foreach (overlay_nearest(@layer, $geometry, limit:=2), length (make_line ( $geometry, @element))))
   ```

In this step, it seems that the result is correct, but it is not clear to me that it is necessary to use the function `array_sum`.

2. Then I use the Geometry generator with the following expression that tries to integrate the previous function of distance calculation with the creation of buffers:

```
with_variable(
    'distance',
        array_sum ( array_foreach ( overlay_nearest( @layer, $geometry, limit:=2), length (make_line ($geometry, @element)))),
    collect_geometries(
        array_foreach(array_foreach(
                overlay_nearest( 
                    'point_layer',
                    $geometry, 
                    limit:=1),
                make_line(
                    $geometry,  
                    @element)),
            if (
                distance( 
                    start_point (@element), 
                    end_point ( @element))<@distance, 
                buffer (@element,@distance/2),
                buffer (@element,-@distance)))))
```

As you can see, with this expression I manage to draw the buffers. This is just a working idea.

Can you help with a new approach to enable me to complete the goal?

Previous result:

[image]

**Attempt to implement the solution by [@JGH](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84870/jgh) user**

I have implemented the solution proposed by user [@JGH](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84870/jgh) but it does not give the expected result. It seems that the virtual layer only loads 5 points:

[image]

It seems to be calculating the cumulative distance of 5 points. I am not sure.

It seems also that the distance values are too high.

Comment: Never compute distances using `3857`. Use a suitable local projection that preserve distances (UTM or else). Also make sure each point has its own ID (no duplicates)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need the computed distance to classify the output. One option is to create a virtual layer that will compute the distance, record it, buffer the point and that you can style as you wish using the `rule based symbology`.

[image]

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Replace `myPointLayer` with the real layer name, and you can add other fields from `pt1`.

```sql
SELECT pt1.id, pt2.id as nerest_pt_id,
       MIN(ST_Distance(pt1.geometry, pt2.geometry)) AS distance,
       st_buffer(pt1.geometry, MIN(ST_Distance(pt1.geometry, pt2.geometry))) as geometry
FROM myPointLayer AS pt1, myPointLayer AS pt2
WHERE pt1.id != pt2.id
GROUP BY pt1.id
ORDER BY distance DESC
```

Answer (score 7):

**Alternative solution**

I use Rule-based symbology with the following expressions:

For Filter (calculate distances for each point and select distance <0.7):

```
distance(
  $geometry,
  array_get(
    overlay_nearest(
      layer:=@layer,
      expression:=$geometry,
      limit:=2
    ),
    1
  )
)<0.7
```

For the Geometry generator (draw buffers at distance):

```
with_variable(
    'dista',
distance(
  $geometry,
  array_get(
    overlay_nearest(
      layer:=@layer,
      expression:=$geometry,
      limit:=2
    ),
    1
  )
),
    collect_geometries (
        array_foreach (
            array_foreach (
                overlay_nearest( 
                    'point_layer',
                    $geometry, 
                    limit:=1
                ),
                make_line (
                    $geometry,  
                    @element
                )
            ),
            if (
                distance( 
                    start_point (@element), 
                    end_point (@element)
                )<@dista, 
                buffer(@element,@dista/1),
                buffer(@element,-@dista)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The result:

[image]